# Want to specify rules in VirtualService file where two or more services have same rules

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, gateway

I have deployed eight services on Kubernetes with Istio sidecar injection.
I want to set-up routing rules in VirtualService where three services have same rule.
Rules:-

```
  - match:
    - headers:
        location:
          exact: pune
      uri:
        prefix: /wagholi
    route:
    - destination:
        host: wagholi
        port:
          number: 8080
      uri:
        prefix: /yerwada
    route:
    - destination:
        host: yerwada
        port:
          number: 8080
      uri:
        prefix: /hadapsar
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hadapsar
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - headers:
        location: 
          exact: mumbai
      uri:
        prefix: /chatraparishivajiterminal
    route:
    - destination:
        host: chatraparishivajiterminal
        port:
          number: 8080
      uri:
        prefix: /kalyan
    route:
    - destination:
        host: kalyan
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - headers:
        location: 
          exact: Pimpari
      uri:
        prefix: /akurdi
    route:
    - destination:
        host: akurdi
        port:
          number: 8080
      uri:
        prefix: /ravet
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ravet
        port:
          number: 8080
```

In this scenario, If I set location pune in headers and then try to call service with name wagholi it should call wagholi and if I hit hadapsar then hadapsar. 
If I set the location as Pimpri and call ravet then it should call ravet only.
Is there any scenario to do so !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a reproduction of your question with 3 simple nginx pods, the problem is I couldn't make it work with just 1 header and 3 uri.

So i made it another way, every match of virtual service has it's own header and uri.

Check below example.

We have **3 pods ->  3 services -> [virtual service](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) -> [gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) -> ingressgateway**

**Deployment 1**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

**Deployment 2**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx2
        app: frontend2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx2 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

**Deployment 3**

```
piVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx3
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx3
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx3
        app: frontend3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx3
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx3 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
```

**Service 1**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend
```

**Service 2**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  labels:
    app: frontend2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend2
```

**Service 3**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx3
  labels:
    app: frontend3
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend3
```

**Virtual Service**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
spec:
  gateways:
  - mesh # traffic inside cluster
  - comp-ingress-gateway # traffic from outside cluster
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  - nginx.com # outside cluster
  - nginx3.default.svc.cluster.local
  - nginx2.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: a
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /wagholi
      headers:
        location:
          exact: pune
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - name: b
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /yerwada
      headers:
        location:
          exact: pune
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx2.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - name: c
    match:
    - uri:
       prefix: /hadasapar
      headers:
        location:
          exact: pune
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx3.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

**Gateway**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: comp-ingress-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
```

**Some ubuntu pod to test inside traffic**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubu1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubu1
    image: ubuntu
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && sleep 3000"]
```

And the results:

**Inside**:

```
root@ubu1:/# curl -H "location: pune" nginx/wagholi
Hello nginx1
root@ubu1:/# curl -H "location: pune" nginx/hadasapar
Hello nginx3
root@ubu1:/# curl -H "location: pune" nginx/yerwada  
Hello nginx2
```

**Outside**:

```
curl -H "location: pune" -H "host: nginx.com" ingress_gateway_ip/hadasapar
Hello nginx3
curl -H "location: pune" -H "host: nginx.com" ingress_gateway_ip/wagholi
Hello nginx1
curl -H "location: pune" -H "host: nginx.com" ingress_gateway_ip/yerwada
Hello nginx2
```

---

**EDIT**

> How Can I find ingress_gateway_ip?

You Can use

```
kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```

And it's [istio-ingressgateway](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/) EXTERNAL-IP

> If the EXTERNAL-IP value is set, your environment has an external load balancer that you can use for the ingress gateway. If the EXTERNAL-IP value is  (or perpetually ), your environment does not provide an external load balancer for the ingress gateway. In this case, you can access the gateway using the service’s [node port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport).

---

> Can I do differently Ingress for each service and then map to VirtualService.

I'm not sure about that but i think it's possible. Check below links

- [How to create custom istio ingress gateway controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835752/how-to-create-custom-istio-ingress-gateway-controller)
- https://discuss.istio.io/t/how-to-run-multiple-ingress-gateway-with-different-class-names/1866

I hope it will help You. Let me know if You have any more questions.

Comment: How Can I find `ingress_gateway_ip`?

Comment: Can I do differently **Ingress** for each service and then map to VirtualService.

Comment: How can I access this from Browser